# How to return environment values in jenkins declarative pipeline to a file?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile as below and

- i am passing environment variables per stage,
- want to create a `docker.env` file using these environment variables,
- so i can use this docker.env file as part of my docker run `'docker run -d --env-file=docker.env java'` per stage
- **looking for a `<command_to_copy_all_values_under_'environment'_to_file_'docker.env'>` ???**

#### Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Staging') {
      environment {
        KEY1_1=VALUE1_1
        KEY1_2=VALUE1_2
        KEY2_1=VALUE2_1
        KEY2_2=VALUE2_2
      }
      steps {
        timestamps() {
          deleteDir()
          sh '''
         <command_to_copy_all_values_under_above_'environment'_to_file_'docker.env'>
             docker run -d --env-file=docker.env java
'''
        }

      }
    }
    stage('Production') {
      when {
        branch 'release'
      }
      environment {
        KEY1_1=VALUE1_1
        KEY1_2=VALUE1_2
        KEY2_1=VALUE2_1
        KEY2_2=VALUE2_2
      }
      steps {
        timestamps() {
          timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            input 'Ready to deploy to PRODUCTION, click PROCEED or ABORT ?'
          }
          deleteDir()
          sh '''
             <command_to_copy_all_values_under_above_'environment'_to_file_'docker.env'>
             docker run -d --env-file=docker.env java
'''
        }
      }
    }
  }
  tools {
    maven 'apache_maven_352'
  }
  environment {
        KEY1=VALUE1
        KEY2=VALUE2
        KEY3=VALUE3
        KEY4=VALUE4
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the braces supposed to nest?  They don't in the example input.

Comment: yes @user464502 they are supposed to...updated my example...

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution with AWK:

```
awk -v B1="block-2" -v B2="block-Y" '/^[^ \t]/ { main=$1; next } main==B1 && $1==B2 { fnd=1; next } $1=="}" { fnd=0 } fnd && $0~/=/ { gsub(/^[ \t]+/,""); print $0 }' YOURFILE
```

Output:

```
key2_1=value2_1
key2_2=value2_2
```

Comment: thank you @andriy this worked perfectly for my earlier example, unfortunately i havent posted the actual scenario where this wasn't working.....re-edited my post with my exact case.....